# How to test for contrasts and interpret multiple meta-regression in metafor

Tags: r, meta-analysis, meta-regression, metafor

Lets say I was meta-analysing studies which have assessed the influence of a warm- up on running performance (completely hypothetical). Lets also say that I wanted to find out whether pre-exercise nutrition, the duration of the warm up, and the type of music had any influence.

```
Nutrition<- c("Meal", "Shake", "Nothing")
Duration<- c("Long", "Short")
Music<- c("Self-selected", "Pre-determined"
```

For Nutrition, the reference level is "Meal". For duration, the reference level is "Long". For music, the reference level is "Self-selected". I then build the following mixed effects model using the excellent package `metafor` and assume that these are additive (for simplicities sake).

```
rma.mv(yi= effect, V= samp_var, slab= Auth, Data= Final_Dat, mods= ~ Nutrition + Duration + Music, method "REML", random= ~ Study/Outcome)
```

Having gotten this far, let's say I receive the following output from the model.

```
intercept= 15.50
Nutrition Shake= -2.620
Nutrition Nothing = -5.387
Duration short = - 2.113
Music Pre-determined= 4.2
```

Now based on my reading, and previous stats knowledge, I understand that the intercept is the estimated effect of having a long warm-up with self-selected music following a proper meal. I also understand that coefficients 2 and 3 represent the difference between that level of the factor and the intercept. Based on this my questions are as follows:

Q1: I assume for coefficients 2& 3, the levels of the other factor(s) are held constant? So, in this case, coefficient 2 would be the estimated average difference in running performance when a shake is consumed before a long warm up with self-selected music. Is this the correct interpretation?

Q2: What is the interpretation of coefficients 4&5? Are these similar to 2&3 in that the other categories are held constant? That is, would the interpretation of coefficient 4 be "the average difference in effect between a short warm-up performed to self-selected music after a meal" or is this just the average difference between a short and long warm up, irrespective of the level of the other categories?

Q3: How do I calculate comparisons for those not explicitly reported in the output. That is, what if I wanted to know whether there was a difference between consuming nothing when a short warm-up is completed with pre-determined music?

I tried reading: https://www.metafor-project.org/doku.php/tips:multiple_factors_interactions. This has some excellent information and examples, but I was wondering if anyone could help extending this to the case where categorical moderators are >2. It seems the general way to do this would be to perform an `anova` with the coefficients specified in someway, or through the `glht` function of the `multicomp` package. However, I'm just looking for a bit more guidance on how this would actually be implemented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Q1: I assume for coefficients 2& 3, the levels of the other factor(s) are held constant? So, in this case, coefficient 2 would be the estimated average difference in running performance when a shake is consumed before a long warm up with self-selected music. Is this the correct interpretation?

In short, no. Coefficient 2 is the effect of consuming a shake irrespective of the duration or the type of music. It is assumed to be the same unless you fit an interaction.

I think, at least in part, that also answers Q2 and Q3.

Comment: thanks for your response here. I think this makes sense to me. So in this case coefficient 4 represents the difference between a short warm-up and long warm-up (reference), irrespective of the music choice and ""food type" consumed? The only part I didn't quite grasp was the "assumed to be the same unless you fit an interaction". What is assumed to be the same? I assume it is the the effect across levels?

Comment: Yes, the effect of warm-up is the same for every music choice unless you fit an interaction.

Comment: Thank you again for your time and help on this!